# Javascript - Returning the value of a return function

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, return-value, return-type

I'm working on a project right now which is primarily front end UI.

Right now i'm encountering an issue with one of my functions, in which the return value is returning the function itself and not the production of the function.

**I'll first start by explaining the expected results**:

1.) There is a menu on the page, when clicking on a button in the menu another menu is added to the page with it's own buttons - *i'll refer to this as the sub menu.*

2.) When clicking the button available in the *sub menu*, another *menu* is create and added to a list elsewhere on the page.

**I'll explained the code that I have, as well as where the issue lies below:**

1.) Here is where the **menu** button is created:

```
var add = document.createElement('button');
```

2.) Here is where I add the event listener to the button above:

```
closure = (function(arrayItem) 
{
    var test = function(event)
    { 
        object.spaces.push(selectedSpace.id);
        object.spaceobjects.push(selectedSpace);

        var enemyPanel = addEntityPanel(roomnumber, selectedSpace.id, object, object.savelocation, true);

        return enemyPanel ;
    };

return test;

})(arrayItem);

add.addEventListener("click", closure, false);
```

*I used the variable closure and passed it an anonymous function for closure reasons, this way the variable **arrayItem** can be modified through a for loop.*

You may notice the function addEntityPanel, this function creates the **menu** that I've been referring to and adds it to the list, it also returns an object with all of the html elements used to create the menu - storing it in the variable `enemyPanel`.

`enemyPanel` from the test function is returned to the variable `test` and test is returned to the variable `closure` which is supposed to give me access to the object enemyPanel created in the addEntityPanel function; however all that is being returned is the function itself as a string. I've tried to change:

```
return test;
```

to

```
return test();
```

But all this does is execute the function when the button in the sub menu is created. I only want it to be executed when the button is clicked.

I'm not too familiar with closure, so if there's something wrong with the closure function preventing it from generating the desired output - I would not be surprised.

I'm open to any and all suggestions. Please let me know what you guys think, thank you!

Comment: What do you want to do with `enemyPanel`? You can't do anything with it in `closure`; by the time a click occurs, `closure` has already returned.

Comment: I have a separate switch statement that takes the object being passed into addEntityPanel that takes the enemyPanel from the function and appends additional children to based on the 'type' property of the object. I can create and append the enemyPanel, but I can't append anything to the enemyPanel without access to it. - i'm running some tests now to see if there is another way for me to access the enemyPanel.

Comment: Put that logic into a function, and call that function from your event handler, passing in the panel.

Answer (score 1):

> ...`enemyPanel` from the `test` function is returned to the variable `test`...

No, it isn't. You're assigning the function itself to the variable `test`, not the result of calling it.

There are two issues:

1. You're passing the wrong function to `addEventListener`. It should be `test`, the function created by `closure`, not `closure`.

   ```
   add.addEventListener("click", test, false);
   ```
2. You're returning `enemyPanel` from the event handler. The return value of an event handler added via `addEventListener` [is completely ignored](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html).¹ You can't *return* `enemyPanel` to anything. You can create it, assign it to a variable that's in scope for that function, add it to a list, etc., but you can't *return* it anywhere from within the event handler.

---

¹ That's a post on my anemic little blog.

Comment: @JonathanHinds - Sorry, completely missed that bit and what you were doing with `closure`. Fixed.